# How to use setup project resource in installer class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I wrote a method in `C# installer class` which explicitly use `abcd.txt`. Everytime my users have to put `abcd.txt` in `System32` folder at the time of installation. So that installer class can use it.

Now i have added `abcd.txt` in my `setup project`. Is it possible to access that file from `installer class` with code?

Comment: Your application should not be adding *anything* to system folders like `system32`. Those are reserved for system files, not application files. I can guarantee that `abcd.txt` is not distributed with any version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Put your file in application folder and this will copy your file at user given location. After that you can copy this file into system32 folder by using following code:

```
string targetDir = this.Context.Parameters["TargetDir"];
string destpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
string filename = targetDir + "\filename";
File.Copy(filename, destpath);
```

Place the code in the `_AfterInstall` event of the `Installer` class.

and you can access this file also in this event and modify if you want.